# Ionic and Electron Application does not start. Error Launching App, Cannot find module at {Project Directory}

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic3, electron

Ive been trying to convert an ionic application to a desktop application but cant seem to find a solution. Whenever i run `electron .`, i get a pop up that says 
[image: Error launching app]

I have added my main script to my package.json and added a custom build command which builds my app and runs electron afterwards. My package.json looks like this

```
{
"name": "businessapp-desktop",
"version": "0.0.1",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
  "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
  "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
  "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
  "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
  "electon-serve": "ionic-app-scripts build && electron ."
},
"main":"electron/electron.js",
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
  "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
  "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
  "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
  "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
  "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
  "@ionic-native/core": "~4.17.0",
  "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.17.0",
  "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.17.0",
  "@ionic/pro": "2.0.3",
  "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
  "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
  "ionicons": "3.0.0",
  "rxjs": "5.5.11",
  "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
  "zone.js": "0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.1",
  "electron": "^3.0.10",
  "typescript": "~2.6.2"
},
"description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

And my `electron.js` looks like this

```
const electron = require('electron');
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app;
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window 
will 
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1200, height: 700});

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    const startUrl = process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL || url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/../www/index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
             slashes: true
        });
    mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);
    // Open the DevTools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
})
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
// On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
// to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
}
});

app.on('activate', function () {
// On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
// dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
}
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

I have installed electron dependencies with 
`npm i --save-dev electron`
But whenever i try to run `electron .` as stated in the tutorial [here](https://robferguson.org/blog/2017/11/09/build-a-desktop-application-with-ionic-3-and-electron/) i get the error above.

I would appreciate any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed it. The problem was typographical. My app couldnt get to the main.js because the file path was wrong. If youre having a similar problem check your file path.